# I do not understand how to build sets for each classroom

Tags: python

My main objective of this function is to check whether a professor is teaching two courses at the same time.

```
def FacultyMemberOnneClass(self):
    for P in ProfessorList:
        for CL in ClassRoomList:
            for CO in CourseList:
                if CO.ProfessorId  == P.ProfessorId: 
                    Start = CO.StartTime() 
                    End = CO.EndTime() 
                    TimeRange = range(Start, End, .25) 
                    TimeRangeSet = Set(TimeRange)
```

Comment: My main objective here is to find out what your problem actually is. You haven't posted a question, merely a statement with a snippet of code.

Comment: This code makes me sad. Please read [Style Guide for Python Code](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear what your input data looks like, so I'm going to make some assumptions.

First I am going to assume that you have a discrete set of teaching periods per week - say, `['Monday 9am-10am', 'Monday 10am-11am', ...]` and so on, and that every class schedule consists of a subset of these teaching periods.

Second I will assume that each set of periods runs for exactly one whole term - no partial terms - and that we are considering exactly one term's courses at a time.

Third I will assume that all classes are distinct - you can't have MATH101 and ARTMATH101 sharing a room and a professor - if a teacher is teaching one course, he can't (legally) be teaching another course at the same time; in other words, there are no exceptions to the 'can only be teaching one class at once' rule.

```
class Professor(object):
    def __init__(self, name, id):
        self.name = name
        self.id = id

class Course(object):
    def __init__(self, professor_ids, periods):
        self.professors = set(professor_ids)
        self.periods = periods  # where 'period' is an enum of all teaching periods in a week

from collections import Counter

def is_professor_double_booked(professor, all_courses):
    # find all courses taught by this professor
    pcourses = [course in all_courses if professor.id in course.professor_ids]
    # count how many times each period is booked
    period_bookings = Counter(p for course in pcourses for p in course.periods)
    # return (any period booked twice?)
    return len(period_bookings) and (period_bookings.most_common()[0][1] > 1)

def professors_who_are_double_booked(professors, courses):
    for prof in professors:
        if is_professor_double_booked(prof, courses):
            print(prof.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little unsure of the context of your code, but I think you are trying to create a python set of times.

You should take a good look at [datetime](http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFcQFjAA&url=http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html&ei=C3P2T_HcF6qtiQfDofzkBg&usg=AFQjCNGrx18FWluWVtjlxQl1y7-oUD_Dog) datatypes. The code below assumes that you are trying to create a set of type datetime.time . I have tested this in Python2.6 .

```
import datetime

start = datetime.datetime(2012,1,1,9,0) # 09:00 
end = datetime.datetime(2012,1,1,17) # 17:00
intervalSeconds = (end-start).seconds # seconds between start and end time.
intervalBlocks = intervalSeconds / (60*15) # 15 minute blocks between start and end time.

timeRange = [(start + datetime.timedelta(minutes=15*i)).time()
    for i in range(intervalBlocks+1)]
timeRangeSet = set(timeRange)
```